# $4^{2a+1}$+$(1/4)^{2a-1}$=$2017$, find $2^{a+1}$+$(1/2)^{a-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4^{2a+1}$+$(1/4)^{2a-1}$=$2017$, find $2^{a+1}$+$(1/2)^{a-1}$. So what I tried was simplifying the first equation to $4^{2a+1}$+$4^{-2a+1}$=$2017$. However, this didn't lead me to anythings so I simplified the second equation to $2^{a+1}$+$2^{-a+1}$. This also lead me to a dead end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Divide the equation by $4$ giving
$$4^{2a}+4^{-2a}=\frac{2017}{4}$$
Now complete the square.....

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $x=2^a+2^{-a}\,$, then:

- $x^2=2^{2a}+2^{-2a}+2=4^a+4^{-a}+2\,$
- $(x^2-2)^2=4^{2a}+4^{-2a}+2=\frac{2017}{4}+2$

Comment: So would I do $x^2$=$sqrt(2017/4)+4$ then solve for $x$=$sqrt(sqrt(2017/4)+4)$. Then multiply everything by two to get the answer?

Comment: @jonyoung2002 Careful with the square roots. Next step would be $x^2-2=\sqrt{\frac{2017}{4}+2}=\sqrt{\frac{2025}{4}}=\frac{45}{2}\,$.